# Is it possible to remove logo from first slide in Quarto-Revealjs presentation?

Tags: css, quarto, reveal.js

I am developing a Quarto/Revealjs extension to implement the slide presentation template of my company.
I am almost done with my work except for one small - but annoying - thing. I need to add a logo at the upper-right corner of each slide, except for the title slide. I know I can add a logo to each slide using the `logo` option in the YAML header but I cannot figure out how to remove it from the first slide.
I have tried multiple solutions among which:

1. Removing the `logo` option in the YAML and trying to add a resized background image at the top-right corner modifying the .css file but the image covers the entire slide (background-size option in the .css doesn't seem to work).
2. Trying to implement the solution proposed [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/557), adding a java script after the body. It simply does not work.

[Here](https://github.com/giuliomela/rse_temp) the link to the gitHub page of my extension.

Can anyone help? I think this is a pretty straightforward customisation but I am really stuck.

Comment: Please not that code relevant to your question generally belongs directly into your question, not just dumped onto some external repo. In this case here however I would not know what of that is actually relevant to begin with. Stuff like template files of around 10MB in size is probably not what anyone here wants to go through in the first place. But I am guessing your problem could likely be solved using CSS in the first place, by using the `:first-child` selector in the appropriate context. Can you show what the resulting HTML looks like?

Comment: I apologize, I know that it should be better to include the code directly into the question but my point is that I do not have any specific code to show... I know how to add a logo to my presentation template (using to `logo` option in the YAML) but I have no clue on how to exclude the first slide... 

I tried to circumvent the problem by setting a small background image to all slides with the following code in the custom.css:

`.slide-background-content{
  background-image: url(logo.jpg);
  background-size: 15%;
  background-position: 80% 15%;
}`

It did not work.

Comment: I am far to be a css expert but I see how `:first-child` can be useful. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

The logo in burnt into the background image. You can override that with the following:

```
.reveal .slide-background-content {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#80b882, #37578b) !important;
}
```